# Как устроены ссылки в Java?

Tags: java, c++

Попробовав Rust после C++, я узнал, что там есть огромное преимущество под названием "заимствование". Эта особенность не даёт скомпилировать примерно такой код:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> vec{"Volvo", "BMW"};

  std::string& ref = vec[0];
  vec.push_back("Mercedes");

  std::cout << ref << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Такой код в C++ приводит к неопределённому поведению (undefined behavior). Недавно я задался вопросом, а как с этим в Java и решил скомпилировать и запустить аналогичный код:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Volvo");
    list.add("BMW");

    String first = list.get(0);
    list.add("Mercedes");

    System.out.println(first);
  }
}
```

Как и ожидалось, в Java ссылка на первый элемент массива последовала за массивом (как я понимаю, здесь, также как в C++, массив изменил своё расположение после вызовов `add`) и продолжила "ссылаться" на нужный элемент.

Почему в Java такое:

1. компилируется
2. ссылка продолжает ссылаться на тот же элемент массива ?

Comment: В примере java ссылки на первый элемент массива нет, есть только ссылка на объект, на который ссылался первый элемент массива в тот момент.

Comment: В случае C++ вектор хранит в себе непосредственно объекты string, а в случае Java ArrayList хранит ссылки на объекты String. В случае C++ переменная ref ссылается внутрь вектора, а в случае Java переменная first ссылается непосредственно на объект String и уже не имеет никакого отношения к ArrayList

Answer (score 2):

На Java невозможно сделать аналогичный код, это типобезопасный язык, без указателей на "сырую память".

Ваш код для Java почти аналогичен коду C++:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {  
  std::vector<std::string> vec;
  vec.push_back("Volvo");
  vec.push_back("BMW");

  std::string first = vec[0];
  vec.push_back("Mercedes");

  std::cout << first << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Что бы восполнить недостаток функционала из за отсутствия указателей, в Java есть мягкие, слабые и фантомные ссылки.

В C++ менеджер памяти может добавить новое значение, если в выделенном alloc'е памяти хватает, если памяти не хватает менеджер памяти выделит новый alloc, и сформирует новый массив с добавленным значением.

В Java такое неопределенное поведение не получиться создать, так как массив `String[]` не позволяет добавлять новые значения, а список не переместит существующие значения в новую память. Но можем имитировать оба варианта:

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new StringBuilder("Volvo").toString());
        list.add(new StringBuilder("BMW").toString());

        WeakReference first = new WeakReference(list.get(0));
        System.out.println(first.get()); //Вернет "Volvo"
        
        //Имитируем первый вариант (памяти в alloc'е хватает):
        {
            list.add(new StringBuilder("Mercedes").toString());
            
            System.gc();
            System.out.println(first.get());//Вернет "Volvo"
        }
        
        //Имитируем второй вариант (памяти в alloc'е не хватает):
        {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(new StringBuilder("Volvo").toString());
            list.add(new StringBuilder("BMW").toString());
            list.add(new StringBuilder("Mercedes").toString());
            
            System.gc();
            System.out.println(first.get()); //Вернет null
        }
    }
}
```